# Looking for a better way to rewrite my messy codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making an app using Rails. I have 4 boolean columns in a table lilke below, and I want to show a message if that column is true.

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.integer :user_id, null: false, default: 0
      t.string :title, null: false, default: ''
      t.text :description, null: true
      t.boolean :tag_1, null: false, default: false
      t.boolean :tag_2, null: false, default: false
      t.boolean :tag_3, null: false, default: false
      t.boolean :tag_4, null: false, default: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <ul>
    <% if post.tag_1 %>
      <li><%= 'tag_name_A' %></li>
    <% end %>
    <% if post.tag_2 %>
      <li><%= 'tag_name_B' %></li>
    <% end %>
    <% if post.tag_3 %>
      <li><%= 'tag_name_C' %></li>
    <% end %>
    <% if post.tag_4 %>
      <li><%= 'tag_name_D' %></li>
    <% end %>
    <% if !post.tag_1 && !post.tag_2 && !post.tag_3 && !post.tag_4 %>
      <li>none</li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

So 'tag_name_A' will be shown if `tag_1` is the only true column, and there'll be 'tag_name_B' & 'tag_name_D' shown if `tag_2` and `tag_4` are both true. (I hope I'm making myself clear.)
These codes are actually working fine and I'm already getting what I want, but I just don't like how they are written. It looks messy and obviously not smart. (You can tell that I'm a newbie.) Is there a better way to rewrite them?

Comment: If the code works as intended, you should probably ask this at Code Review instead.

Comment: I didn't know such service existed... Thanks!